# How UICollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath works?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I create a new project which only contains a `UICollectionView` and a `UIButton`. The collectionView contains 30 cells all in the section 0. And not all the cells can be visible at the same time.

The button's action is here:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 29, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .CenteredVertically, animated: false)
    print(collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
}
```

In the simulator, when touch up inside the button, the collectionView scrolls to the last cell. And after that, print the indexPaths of visible cells to the console.

The problem is that I can't find the last cell's indexPath being printed after touch the button. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, even you call "scrollToItemAtIndexPath" without animation, however, when it is executed, cells between the last visible cell to the last cell will be created and rendered. Moreover, the collection view will layout subviews during that time. So that your "print" call will be executed before. I printed out "cellForItemAtIndexPath" to prove that. One more thing is if you call "print" delay after 0.5s for example, it will print the last cell.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func didButtonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        let section = 0
        let lastItemIndex = self.collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section) - 1
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forItem: lastItemIndex, inSection: section)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)

        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print(self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
        }

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(80, 80)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 60
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        print(indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This works. Thank you! Can I have access to get the new visible cells as soon as the scrolling action finishes? Or are there any ways to force the collectionView to update after scrolling? I have tried all the `setNeed***()` functions of `UICollectionView`, but none of them works.

Comment: You can get the new visible cells as soon as it displayed by implement this method - willDisplayCell
=============
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //To check the last cell will be displayed( or probably whatever index you want)
        let lastItemIndex = self.collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1
        if (indexPath.row == lastItemIndex) {
            
        }
    }
==============

Comment: If you want to know when exactly the scrollview finished loading layout completely, you can add observer on "contentSize" property. Whenever it triggered, you will able to know that collection view has been loaded completely.